# Where was environment variable set?

Tags: macos, environment-variables

I've an environment variable (`$M2_HOME`) which I'd like to modify. The thing is, I can't find where I originally set it - this is quite bizarre as I exclusively use `~/.bash_profile`.

Are there any commands I can use to somehow reflectively inspect set environment variable?

Comment: I assume you use Maven? Can you tell us more about how this variable is being used? Is it *always* set, even if you don't actually run anything related to Maven? Does it maybe have a configuration file that is parsed when it's run?

Comment: In the latter case, why not do a search for the occurrence of `M2_HOME` somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

No, the only thing you can do is search all possible locations.

The environment is just a list of C strings in "key=value" format, it does not carry any metadata about when and where the variables have been set.